# how can i marge two table as single table like view or any other process?

Tags: mysql, cakephp-2.0

how can i marge two table as single table like view or any other proces

table1
 [image: table1]

table2
[image: table2]

[image: result should be]
result should be

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
(
SELECT
    `a`.`id` AS `id`,
    `a`.`name` AS `name`,
    'table1' AS `TABLE_NAME`
FROM
   `table1` `a`
ORDER BY
    `a`.`role`
LIMIT 5
)
UNION
(
SELECT
    `b`.`id` AS `id`,
    `b`.`student_name` AS `student_name`,
    'tavle2' AS `TABLE_NAME`
FROM
    `table2` `b`
ORDER BY
    `b`.`student_role`
LIMIT 5
)
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `union all`

```
select *, 'table1' as table_name from table1
union all
select *, 'table2' as table_name from table2
```

make sure both tables have same no. of columns, If not then specify the column names which you need like select col1,col2...

If you want to create a new table then

```
create table new_table
select *, 'table1' as table_name from table1
union all
select *, 'table2' as table_name from table2
```

[CREATE TABLE ... SELECT Syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-select.html)